# Questions on The Schwarz-Christoffel integral

Tags: complex-analysis

I am studying the Schwarz-Christoffel integral, which are some beautiful conformal map from the upper-half plane to polygons. But I have some questions on the detail of the integral. They are, I guess, some basic facts about complex integral I missed before. I hope someone can help clarify the details, which I really want to understand well. Thanks a lot in advance.

Here is the definition of the Schwarz-Christoffel integral. Given $A_1<A_2<...<A_n$ on the real line, $\beta_1,...,\beta_n<1,$ with $\sum\beta_k<1$

The integral is defined as follows:

$S(z):=\int_0^z \frac{ds}{(s-A_1)^{\beta_1}...(s-A)^{\beta_n}}$

The following questions arises when I was reading E. Stein's Complex analysis:

1. "since $\beta_k<1$, $(s-A_k)^{-\beta_k}$ is integrable", I know the real integral $\int_0^x\frac{1}{x^\alpha}$ is finite when $\alpha<1$. But I do not understand why it is the same in the complex contour inegral. Also, even $(s-A_k)^{-\beta_k}$ is integrable, why the product $\prod_1^n(s-A_k)^{-\beta_1}$ is still integrable.
2. "$S(z)$ is continuous up to the real line." I am not sure about the continuity of complex integral. In real analysis, if the function is absolutely convergent, then its integral is continuous. I am wondering is it true that the complex contour integral is continuous whenever it is well-defined?
3. Fundamental theorem of Calculus in complex contour integral. In the discussion of Schwarz-Christoffel integral, Stein used the fact that $S'=\frac{ds}{(s-A_1)^{\beta_1}...(s-A)^{\beta_n}}$. I know that the integral of the derivative is the difference of the value of the 2 endpoint. But I am not sure if $F'=f(x)$ if $F=\int_a^xf$

Edited: one more question.

4. In the proof of formula for conformal from $\mathbb H$ to polygon $P$. Stein written $C_1\int_0^z \frac{1/s^2}{\prod((A_n-A_k)-1/s)^{\beta_k}}+C_2=C_1\int_0^z \frac{1}{\prod((A_n-A_k)s-1)^{\beta_k}}+C_2$, here $\sum\beta_k=2$. It seems that the property $(zw)^\alpha=z^\alpha w^\alpha$, but I guess it is not generally true?